# Visual Studio 2013 Website refresh/restart ignores code changes

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express

When I have a website in VS2013 (either a web-application or a web-type project), and I make a change to the code, such as a JS change or an HTML change, this change is not reflected in the browser after a refresh. The following are the things I have tried which did *not* work:

- Clearing browser cache/restarting browser
- Stopping VS debug, and restarting project
- Cleaning VS solution, rebuilding, and restarting
- Cleaning VS solution, shutting down VS, and completely restarting VS
- Browser link refresh

The only way I can get my code changes to take effect (either JS or html) is to either manually quit IISExpress/VS and restart my computer.

Without being too dramatic, this is unacceptable. How do I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I too have come across the same issue and it seems that it comes from  `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET` files.

If you delete these files and reload your page everything works. I'm still unsure why Visual Studio is not updating these files.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue and it appeared as if IIS Express was running an older branch of my code even though I was launching from the newer branch. Try shutting down Visual Studio and re-opening the project.