# Why I have to restart IIS even if I change image?

Tags: asp.net, iis, build, webforms

I have web application in ASP.Net - web form. I have facing weird problem with only this project.

1) When I make any change in code, I have to change port of IIS express to see my change after running. 
2) Even when I change image or javascript and release on live, I need to restart IIS then only it shows updated image or javascript.

I checked but not getting what is the actual cause of this weird issue. It is tedious job to do IIS restart for small image change or even in local change port every time to see my change.

Any help what could be reason?

Comment: Are you sure its `IIS` and not the browser caching ? have you tried `Ctrl+F5`

Comment: Yes, I tried all ways.

Comment: Maybe this is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30238436/7324631)